# Operation in "if" condition

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a VBA code., 
in one scenario
I need to perform operation in condition of if, but system throws error
"Expected Then or Goto"

```
if LineFromFile%23=1 Then
```

LineFromFile indicates number of line from CSV.
Help me!!

Comment: i'd say the % in your variable name is not interpreted as command. and you should close your if statement with an `end if`

Comment: Is LineFromFile defined and set to be the line from your file which you want the IF statement to check? LineFromFile is not a working code on its own in VBA.

Comment: Yes, system throws type mismatch while execute this line "if LineFromFile mod 23=1 Then" any solution for this?

Comment: Is `LineFromFile` defined as something other than a numeric-type variable (`Integer`,`Long`), and does it contain something other than a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if LineFromFile%23=1 Then
```

I get to know my syntax for mod operation is wrong

We can do modulo operation with "mod" keyword

So I change my code as

```
if LineFromFile mod 23=1 Then
```